# I have enabled JavaScript Bundling after that If i am changing in any JS codes it's not reflected on frontend in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, requirejs-config.js

I am trying to update the JS code on the frontend of my website.

I made changes in the checkout page JS files. After changing code, I ran all relevant commands.

```
1. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ar_SA en_GB en_US
2. after running this command running - php bin/magento cache: clean & flush
3. after that putting permission 777.
```

Codes are updating in required js file of pub/static folder but not in frontend browser.

***I have enabled  JavaScript Bundling. I think it's causing me. anyone can help me regarding this.***

I am using Ngnix and Redis Cache.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Which mode have you used 'production' or 'developer'?

Comment: production mode